# Flash - Text changing after chaning frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have custom button made using movieclip. I have a text filed inside it to display text. To show different effect when user over,out and click on the button we added 3 frames with different effects and change the frame using mc.gotoAndStop(x) when user performs some action.

It was working fine till yesterday. But since ever we added effect to the textfield (with different font color and style) the text value of the text field is reverting back to the default/initial value what we set in the design time.

Is this expected? is there a work around for this other than removing effects on the text filed?

I have code(listeners) written out side the component (inside main class, not in timeline)

Comment: Do you have actions layer on that button?

Comment: no timeline code. my listners are outside

Answer (score 0):

Flash timelines are kind of like a static state machine; moving from frame-to-frame runs all of the document code at that frame (every time).  It also resets the value of the content to the state it was in during design time (so, frame = design + code).  Because of the headaches this model can cause, I highly recommend you do all of your design & code in a single frame.

Changing the appearance programmatically is easy enough, though.  Use [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#includeExamplesSummary) and apply it to your [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) with [setTextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29).

```
// Create the textfield
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.text = "Sample Text";
addChild(txt);

// Create the formatting
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Verdana";
format.color = 0xFF0000;
format.size = 10;
format.underline = true;

// Apply the format to the TextField
txt.setTextFormat(format);
```